# Epson WP-4545 Wi-Fi printer on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, printing, epson

When sending a document to my Wi-Fi network Epson WP-4545 printer, it goes through the motions, making all the right noises, but it produces a blank sheet of paper. I'm using Ubuntu 16.04. The printer works fine on tablet and laptop.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Did you install drivers?

Comment: Thanks for the response  [Pilot6] I have installed Epson 201113W

Comment: Install a proprietary driver http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModule

Comment: I have tried this several times and it just seems to go round in circles with no download. Is there any other site for Epson driver downloads?

Comment: Can you explain what "goes in circles"? Did you accept the license? The driver is downloadable from that site.

Comment: Thanks for all your support. The problem has been resolved via terminal commands from a website. Again thanks for all the info and support.